# Related Products block

Tags: ubercart

Hai am working on an ecommerce site using ubercart module. I have created a view for listing products in a particular category. each product direct to a page which consists of its details and add to cart buton. In the bottom of this page i have a related products block which list all the other products in this category.but in this block it repeats the main product once more. how can i remove it? can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add a Contextual Filter field w/c would be the **Content: Nid**
2. In contextual filter Content: Nid configuration, under **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL**, use *Content ID from URL* for the **Type**.
3. In contextual filter Content: Nid configuration, scroll down and toggle open the **More** fieldset and check **Exclude**